# Phenny IRC bot- disconnecting

Tags: python, irc

I am attempting to set up an IRC bot (phenny) and I have gotten as far as editing default.py to say:

```
nick = 'Willdudebot123'
host = irc.freenode.net
channels = ['#FunkyChicken']
owner = 'Willdude123'
```

But when I run phenny.py, it connects to freenode, and then, after about 10 seconds, it drops out. Any ideas? By the way I am on Debian Linux.

Comment: At the very least, more information is required. What does "drops out" mean, how far does it get connecting, is there any error message?. Have you searched for similar sounding problems that didn't fix your problem (provide example links) etc... This question is close to being "off topic"/"not constructive" for S/O...

Comment: Your `host` value looks like it should be a string, but is missing quotes. I doubt you have a `irc` variable, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that's likely a copy/paste error - if the  statement "it connects to freenode[...]" is correct

Comment: @JonClements: Sure, but I'd like the OP to correct it still. :-)

Comment: Yes, the absence of quotes was in erorr. A google for 'phenny irc bot disconnecting from freenode' yields this question as the top result. No solutions found. If needed I can ask elsewhere.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pAufZNXY is the error message.

Comment: I have fixed it, it joins the channel successfully, but does not respond to any commands.

Comment: Well, by the looks of it, when it's trying to handle a request, it's trying to determine if the nickname of the origin is an admin... `self.config.admins` doesn't appear to exist... I can only assume that the config file ('default.py') or something, is supposed to have a `admins = ['list', 'of', 'names']` in there or something so that setting the admin flag is possible...